# PDF is not printing from Windows XP, but works on Windows 7

Tags: c#

The following code successfully prints on Windows 7, but won't work on Windows XP.  Both computers have a default printer setup that works correctly if I go into Notepad and manually print a document.  On the Windows XP box it just sits there, no errors no nothing.

How can I debug this so as to get an error message or some other way to figure out why this isn't printing?

```
try
{
    if (File.Exists(pdfPath))
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = pdfPath;
        process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForInputIdle();
        process.Kill();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The file \"" + pdfPath + "\" does not exist", "File not found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        statusLabel.Text = "";
        return;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Unable to print packing slip", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does it show anyhting in Output Window?

Comment: I'm pretty new to C#, but my application on the destination machine doesn't have an output window that I'm aware of.  I have a status bar there named `statusLabel` that I update manually...

Comment: The Output window is a diagnostic window in Visual Studio; @Bob means to run your app in the debugger.

Comment: Try adding `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true`.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you have differently settings for pdf print in both systems.
Check "print" verb for .pdf filetypes .. in winXP and win7. You get the same results?

For check and compare you can use this software: [nirsoft-file_types_manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html)
Maybe you get link like this:

`print

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" /p "%1"`

**As a solution I propose to do the following steps:**

1. Check "print" verb for PDF in your system. If this verb is missing, then reinstal PDF software.
2. If you get differently commands then try use the same software in both systems. With software from nirsoft you can try edit XP command to fix it (this can be in system if you "incorrectly" uninstalled software for PDF .. if you know path with parameters then you can try edit this command
3. Try use "open" verb if software for opening (and printing) PDF files is installed correctly. If this work and print no, then try reinstal software for PDF.

If all of this steps not help, commands are the same and open file work correctly, then you can try to use command to print PDF directly, to check if command working.

1. In winXP replace %1 with your filename and run this command in Run window (start with shortcut WIN + R) *Warning: your file will be printed if it works*

If it not works, then reinstal PDF software. If it works from command line, but not from you software, then I do not know how to help you.

Comment: Good advice... when I run the command as you suggested it works fine, however when I run the `Print` verb as suggested, it says `myfile.pdf is printing...` and just sits there.  Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: Can you print pdf document from that software you open it by `Open` webr? Is desired printer set as default?
"Just sits there" means you see "printing" message that will not close or open and close without any printing process?

.. ok, we can try check print log:
Open windows Run (WIN + R or Click Start>Run) and type: **eventvwr**
Find system log (sorry I dont have WinXP-in Win7: WindowsLogs - System) and check if documents was printed.

Comment: _How enable PrintService log?_ I dont know how to do this in WinXP maybe this help: [How to audit user access to printers](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310399&Product=winxp) in Win7 you can open Event Viewer - Applications and Services Logs - Microsoft - Windows - PrintService - Operational - Actions:Enable log  
Then you will see any print in this log.  
Is there your printed file visible? Under right printer? .. but still no print? .. and you can print file from that software directly? .. then it is too mysterious for me :)

Comment: Thanks for following up.  The command we execute never shows up there.  At this point I'm accepting that there's something wrong with the PC and am going to wait for them to update it to Windows 7 in hopes that resolves the issue.